# What are Ketephys' subdomains?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, golarion

Is it written anywhere in an official source what Ketephys' subdomains are? Google only responds with a single wiki and about 20 different people quoting that wiki, but not listing a source.

I'm specifically wondering about the Feather domain. I'm having a disagreement with my DM about it, and she wants an actual Pathfinder source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[James Jacob's comment](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5lbwn&page=2?Golarion-Day-Subdomains-for-Everyone#51) on the *Golarion Day: Subdomains for Everyone!* Paizo blog article is the most authoritative source I could find. James Jacobs, a creative director at Paizo, confirmed Ketephys' subdomains: Azata, Feather, Fur, Growth, Seasons and Storms.

Answer (score 3):

[*Inner Sea Gods*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy94wj?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Inner-Sea-Gods-Hardcover) from Paizo clarifies Ketephys's subdomains as Azata, Feather, Fur, Growth, Moon, and Seasons.

The [Pathfinder wiki article on Ketephys](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Ketephys) has been updated to include these subdomains.